# scipy.optimize.curve_fit giving ValueError: object too deep for desired array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sympy

I am trying to use `Sympy` along with `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` to create a script which fits data using a symbolic expression given by the user

I am getting the following error:
`ValueError: object too deep for desired array`

I can not figure out what is causing this problem to appear.

The script I am using:

```
import numpy as np
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr
from sympy import S, Symbol,lambdify
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

# create data
x_data = np.array([[1,2],
                   [2,4],
                   [43,243]])
y_data = 4*x_data[:,0]**2+2*x_data[:,1]+11
y_data = y_data.reshape(-1,1) + np.array([np.random.rand(len(x_data))]).T

# get correlation
correlation = "z=a*x^2+b*y+c"
correlation = correlation.replace("^","**")

# assume variables are x, y and z
symbols = ['x','y','z']

# assume constants are a,b and c
constants_sym = ['a','b','c']

# guess values (first column) and ranges for constants (second and third column)
constants_ranges = np.array([[7,-np.inf,np.inf],
                             [5,-np.inf,np.inf],
                             [1,-np.inf,np.inf],])

# create 2 correlations from left and right hand sides
correlations = [parse_expr(corr) for corr in correlation.split('=')]

# create lambdified functions from each side of the equation
funcs = [lambdify(tuple(symbols+constants_sym), f) for f in correlations]

# define the ojective function
def lambdified_func(x, *constants):
    results = []
    for row in x:
        # find the difference between left and right hand sides
        LHS_RHS = funcs[0](*row,*constants)-funcs[1](*row,*constants)
        results.append(LHS_RHS)
    results = np.array(results).reshape(-1,1)
    return results

results = curve_fit(lambdified_func, # objective function
                    np.hstack([x_data,y_data]), # send both x and y data as x-data
                    np.zeros([len(x_data),1]), # LHS - RHS = 0
                    p0=list(constants_ranges[:,0]), # initital guess
                    bounds=[tuple(constants_ranges[:,1]),tuple(constants_ranges[:,2])], # bounds
                    )
```

Comment: Dont use sympy and scipy together. I take that back - a bit. You use `lambdify`, but in a complex way that I can't follow, at least not without running the code myself (with lots of debugging prints).

Comment: Is that inevitable? is it recommended by either of the modules?

Comment: I qualified that.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it needs traceback and other debugging details

Comment: I actually figured out the issue, which was quite absurd; Not sure if I should answer it or just close the question

Comment: ```scipy.optimize.curve_fit``` requires y_data to be flat, as well as the objective function return

Comment: SymPy and SciPy can be used together: it's just necessary to understand what you are doing. The problem above is a simple mistake and is not caused mixing these two libraries.